# POSTRESQL query use 100% CPU

Tags: apache, postgresql

I use an open source application (Maarch) and after a migration from older version to newer, I have a postgresql problem.

There is two actions, involved pgsql, that use 100% of the CPU and block the application.

I have no apache2 error, no pgsql error neither. I'm currently block for now, cause I don't know where I can search the source of the problem.

The server is under debian 8, with PHP 7.0 and POSTGRESQL 9.4

Any idea ?

Comment: please add `ps aux | grep postgres` to your question, we are not  telepaths :)

Comment: You can display all active queries with `SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity`.

Comment: Have you tried vacuum? restarting the postgresql service? search de log file? use explain for the query? we need more info. As @JustMe says, we are not telepaths.

Comment: Did this *migration* include adding the indexes? Did you run `VACUUM FULL ANALYZE` after this *migration*, or at least `ANALYZE` ? Does the new version have the correct DB-tuning settings ?

Answer (score 0):

Please consider:

- enabling logging of all statements eg http://cheng.logdown.com/posts/2016/04/08/enable-logging-in-postgresql 
  Please note that the above mentioned will slow down the application and may eat a lot of hdd for logs. Please browse / grep the logs.
- executing a few times `select * from pg_stat_activity` this will let you know what queries are running under the hood.
- execute `select * from pg_stat_user_tables` in search for last_vacuum or autovac dates - if correlates to dates of your slowdowns you gov the issue solved.
- execute `SELECT now() - query_start, usename, datname, waiting, state, query FROM  pg_stat_activity WHERE now() - query_start > '5 seconds'::interval ORDER BY 1 DESC;` to determine long lasting queries (above 5 secs.

If the above mentioned will not help please analyze if queries that are being executed are complex and if fields in joins / where sections of the running queries are indexed.

alternatively running a vacuum full with analyze may help a bit (long lasting operation).